# Can't make the code recognize 0 as a value

Tags: javascript

I'm making an editable RPG sheet. For this specific section, I need it to compare the 1_7, 2_7 and 3_7 to the result of the equation, and have it select the smaller value. However, while it works on most situations, it doesn't recognize 0 as a value. 1_7, 2_7 and 3_7 are inputted manually.

What should I do in order to get the code to recognize 0 as a value?

```
var x = 
this.getField("1_7").value;
var y = 
this.getField("2_7").value;
var z = 
this.getField("3_7").value;

var f = Math.floor((this.getField("Des Temp").value - 10) / 2);

var temp;

if(!x)
{
x = f;
}

if(!y)
{
y = f;
}

if(!z)
{
z = f;
}

if(x <= y && x <= z)
temp = x;
else if(y <= z)
temp = y;
else
temp = z;

if(f > temp)
f = temp;

if(f > 0){
event.value = "+" + f;
}
else{
event.value = f;
}
```

Comment: You should use better variables name than only letters.

Answer (score 1):

O is a "falsy" value so

```
if(!x)
```

Is doing what it is supposed to do. The empty value is probably an empty string so you could do

```
if ( ! x.length )
```

instead.

```js
$('#x').on( 'input', function() {
  console.log( ! $(this).val().length );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='x' >
```

Comment: When I do this, the code simply ignores the comparison and just shows the equation result. Maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: Update your question with a minimal runnable snippet and we'll be able to help troubleshoot.

Comment: I don't know how to make a field outside the program for it to consider. This whole thing is actually an edit on someone else's work, but the original also had the same problem concerning 0 as a value.

Comment: Hmmm. Do you have it up on a sandbox or staging server that we could see in action?

Comment: It's on an editable .pdf file, with the named variables being fields that the user fills up with the relevant info. If you want, I can send you that.

Comment: I'm a web guy and don't have acrobat so you might want to start a new question including a link to the pdf and tag pdf in the question. You might get the attention of someone who's better equipped to help.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `0` is considered as `false` inside a javascript comparaison. If you want to verify if the field have data, you can use the `length` property.

```js
var x = 0;
var y = 5;
var z = 3;


var f = 10;

if(0)
{
  console.log("0 is false");
}

if(1)
{
  console.log("1 or any number != 0 is true");
}

if(x.length)
{
  x = f;
  console.log("x is not set");
}

if(y.length)
{
  y = f;
    console.log("y is not set");
}

if(y.length)
{
  z = f;
    console.log("z is not set");
}
```

Comment: When I do this, the result field goes blank and the equation that uses this result as a variable goes crazy. Maybe I'm doing it wrong?